# Find Dockerfile build for `k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10`

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've followed the tutorial here
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper/

which references image `k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10`. I can go to

http://k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper
which redirects to
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL/kubernetes-zookeeper?gcrImageListsize=50

and I can see the built docker image and the manifest.

How can I find the Dockerfile and the source used to build the image. Most other hubs link to the source. I presume the source to this is on github or some similar public repo?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper.yaml)?

Comment: So, you link yaml that absolutely references image `k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10` and looks exactly like the yaml given in the official tutorial. The Dockerfile in that directory has nothing to do with Zookeeper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the github repo with the right Dockerfile and build environment is
https://github.com/kow3ns/kubernetes-zookeeper/tree/master/docker

The Makefile look like it lines up with the image `k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [this is the Dockerfile](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/statefulsets/zookeeper/Dockerfile).

Comment: I believe that is for `gcr.io/google_samples/k8szk:v3`. The github page you links to is titled `K8SZK`. Is there any way I can find out for sure?

Comment: The Dockerfile you link has a zookeeper.yaml right next to it, that references the image `gcr.io/google_samples/k8szk:v3`, so no, this is a different image.